# Where is gravity form data stored?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

The website I'm working on uses gravity forms and gravity form PDFs to generate PDFs from form data. There was a typo in one of the form field options. When I fixed the typo, every entry lost its data for that form field. Thankfully, this happened in a sandbox environment and the staging environment still has all of the information for that form field.

I have gone through every single table on the database and could not find where the information for these entries are stored. I also checked through the local file structure.

Does anyone know where the form field data is stored with Gravity Forms?'

EDIT:
Sorry, it was just mySQLworkbench being stupid. I had my rows set to 1000 and it was displaying 1044. That made me assume there were only 1044 rows... There were thousands of rows I didn't check. I changed my query and that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Any uploaded files will be stored in the wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/$FORM_ID-randomstring folder. Any text entered in your form fields will be store in your WordPress database in dedicated Gravity Forms tables. A reference to any uploaded file will be stored in the database as well.
for more information please click the link https://docs.gravityforms.com/database-storage-structure-reference/ or check out other peoples contribution here >>https://legacy.forums.gravityhelp.com/topic/where-does-the-gravity-form-information-go-after-it-is-created

Comment: Sadly, the information is not stored in any of those databases. However, I did find other form information in the wp_rg_ tables. I also found the images stored in uploads. However I could not find a reference to the uploaded files anywhere in the database

Comment: But were the links any helpful?

Comment: Those were actually some of the first links I looked at during my initial google search. Sadly, they were not helpful.

Comment: You are likely on an older version of Gravity Forms if your data is still in the wp_rg_ prefixed tables. There was a DB migration in 2.3 that happened on upgrade.